# Why NullPointerException in initialising Java Tooling in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

The caption says it all.

1. Why do I get a ***NullPointerException*** when I opened a
   ***workspace*** in ***Eclipse IDE***?
2. Secondly, what does it mean by ***Java Tooling***?

[image]

***Attached Error Log:***

[image]

Comment: Short answer is because some code made inappropriate use of a null reference. For a longer answer, you will have to look into the stacktrace of the said NPE.

Comment: Sometimes happen. My previous Eclipse had this message to the end of life (to install of new version). Seems not be connected with REAL problem (at my computer at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java Tooling** refers to the various aspects of Eclipse that support the development of software using the Java language. It's a rather broad designation.

Your problem seems to be with Spring. Eclipse is trying to connect to http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/updates.xml and is failing (see about halfway down in your problem list). That seems to be causing a cascade of issues all involving the inability of Eclipse to load things related to Spring, presumably because your having trouble accessing the update site.

I opened your Spring URL in my browser. It isn't an Eclipse update site, it's an RSS feed describing Spring updates. That's different. You need to get the correct update site URL or remove Spring (temporarily) from your Eclipse installation.

Comment: What problem it could be as I am connected to the Internet, even before I opened the Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: Edited to address your question

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.